# Why this property of quick sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Why does quick sort sort a given set of already sorted items and reverse sorted items with equal speed.

Why not others like heap sort, insertion sort, or selection sort?

Comment: Worth a read: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257002/what-makes-for-a-bad-case-for-quick-sort

Comment: What do you mean by "with equal speed"? Equal to what?

Comment: The run time of quicksort depends quite a lot on choice of pivot. Name at least five popular methods, and ponder their influence on quicksort's run time on ordered and reversed sequences. Comment on mergesort.

Comment: @greybeard mergesort too has same speed for both cases, is it right? For quick sort it depends on pivot..

Comment: @greybeard - Mergesort on sorted or reverse sorted data does about half the compares, but the same number of moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard selection sort, heap sort and quick sort are not [adaptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort) as insertion sort is.

Look at the table of [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)s comparison.
For example, both the best and the worst case for selection sort has complexity O(n^2) - every cycle run always walks through predetermined piece of array.

Speed of quick sort depends on proper choice of partition elements for given data set. Sorted order may influence, if partition is silly (for example, one always gets the first element of piece), otherwise probability of the worst (quadratic) case is rather small.

If you need to sort almost sorted datasets, choose some adaptive sorting, for example, natural merge sort (or insertion sort for small datasets).